# Swap usage too high?

Tags: linux, debian, memory, swap

I have a Debian Sid box, freshly installed about a month ago, with no desktop apps running at the moment.

Any command I try to run (via ssh) makes the hard disk work very hard. The system worked flawlessly a few weeks ago while running Ubuntu 8.04. Hardware should be ok, smart tools report no problem, nor do memory checks, etc.

I suspect the problem is related to swapping:

```
$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          998M       986M        12M         0B       464K       904M
-/+ buffers/cache:        81M       917M
Swap:         511M       511M         0B
```

Testing stuff, I see that I'm unable to disable swap without rebooting, even though most physical ram is used for caches:

```
# swapoff  -a
swapoff: /swapfile: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

When running the script mentioned in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479953/how-to-find-out-which-processes-are-swapping-in-linux/7180078#7180078), the highest swap-using process was using barely 1.5megs, and the total count was:

```
"Overall swap used: 18376 kB"
```

...which is far from the half gig that htop or free report.

I tried changing the `swappiness` to `1` half a month ago, but there's no difference (same memory usage patterns).

Any idea what could be the culprit?

**Edit**: here's the `/proc/meminfo` contents (similar situation, but 702megs of cache instead of 904, and chromium still open):

```
MemTotal:        1022464 kB
MemFree:           14344 kB
Buffers:             192 kB
Cached:           719816 kB
SwapCached:         2212 kB
Active:           304304 kB
Inactive:         657344 kB
Active(anon):     294128 kB
Inactive(anon):   651264 kB
Active(file):      10176 kB
Inactive(file):     6080 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:        127336 kB
HighFree:            316 kB
LowTotal:         895128 kB
LowFree:           14028 kB
SwapTotal:        524284 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 4 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        239528 kB
Mapped:            11968 kB
Shmem:            703760 kB
Slab:              28924 kB
SReclaimable:      12116 kB
SUnreclaim:        16808 kB
KernelStack:        2200 kB
PageTables:         5812 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1035516 kB
Committed_AS:    2193368 kB
VmallocTotal:     122880 kB
VmallocUsed:       14092 kB
VmallocChunk:     105548 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      911352 kB
DirectMap2M:           0 kB
```

And here's the `top -b -n 1` output:

```
top - 22:00:18 up 1 day,  2:34,  4 users,  load average: 1,97, 1,25, 0,88
Tasks: 137 total,   3 running, 134 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4,9 us,  3,0 sy,  2,7 ni, 83,2 id,  6,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   1022464 total,  1008788 used,    13676 free,      188 buffers
KiB Swap:   524284 total,   524284 used,        0 free,   719792 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 7861 stenyak   20   0  6336 1252  976 R  18,0  0,1   0:00.03 top
 5194 isabel    30  10 44372 5344 1404 R  12,0  0,5   0:36.11 glmatrix
17940 root      20   0  103m 6844 2828 S   6,0  0,7  11:02.21 Xorg
    1 root      20   0  2280   28    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:02.49 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:15.25 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/u:0
    6 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.93 migration/0
    7 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.46 watchdog/0
    8 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.73 migration/1
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:17.30 ksoftirqd/1
   12 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.43 watchdog/1
   13 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 cpuset
   14 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 khelper
   15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   16 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 netns
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.44 sync_supers
   18 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 bdi-default
   19 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
   20 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kblockd
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.07 khungtaskd
   23 root      20   0     0    0    0 D   0,0  0,0   2:50.47 kswapd0
   24 root      25   5     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksmd
   25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 fsnotify_mark
   26 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 crypto
   99 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 khubd
  115 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ata_sff
  116 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0
  117 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1
  118 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:01.66 kworker/u:1
  152 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:02.12 jbd2/sda1-8
  153 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ext4-dio-unwrit
  280 root      20   0  2944  352  128 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.30 udevd
  423 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 hd-audio0
 1286 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:07.06 jbd2/sda2-8
 1287 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ext4-dio-unwrit
 1561 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:03.09 flush-8:0
 1603 root      20   0  2376   48    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.33 rpcbind
 1634 statd     20   0  2648   68   64 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rpc.statd
 1639 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rpciod
 1641 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 nfsiod
 1648 root      20   0  2576    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rpc.idmapd
 2019 root      20   0 29088  976    0 S   0,0  0,1   0:22.26 rsyslogd
 2123 root      20   0  1876   84   24 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.23 acpid
 2161 message+  20   0  3756  728    0 S   0,0  0,1   0:02.06 dbus-daemon
 2213 daemon    20   0  2152   20    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 atd
 2231 root      20   0  4488  220  128 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 bluetoothd
 2242 root      10 -10     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 krfcommd
 2259 avahi     20   0  3272  292  168 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.66 avahi-daemon
 2262 avahi     20   0  3156   24    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 avahi-daemon
 2265 root      20   0  5968  180  152 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 bitlbee
 2271 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:11.69 kworker/0:2
 2304 root      20   0 19056  700  220 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.75 NetworkManager
 2334 root      20   0  5536  176  108 S   0,0  0,0   0:02.86 cron
 2350 root      20   0  6700  492  152 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 sudo
 2351 root      20   0 15304 5880 1428 R   0,0  0,6  61:42.79 iotop
 2359 root      20   0 24256  600   56 S   0,0  0,1   0:01.12 polkitd
 2390 root      20   0  6892  368  180 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.15 modem-manager
 2392 root      20   0  7536   80    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.13 cupsd
 2396 root      20   0 20964  516  296 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.15 gdm3
 2712 root      20   0 10068  196   84 S   0,0  0,0   0:11.72 kerneloops
 2714 root      20   0  6896 2108  372 S   0,0  0,2   0:05.69 ddclient - slee
 2802 Debian-+  20   0  7424  100   40 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.05 exim4
 2877 daemon    20   0  1868  236  172 S   0,0  0,0   0:01.22 uptimed
 2881 root      20   0  6464  208  104 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.27 sshd
 2913 root      20   0  1848   72    8 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 minissdpd
 2936 root      20   0  4328   40   36 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 getty
 2937 root      20   0  4328   40   36 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 getty
 2938 root      20   0  4328   40   36 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 getty
 2939 root      20   0  4328   40   36 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 getty
 2940 root      20   0  4328   40   36 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 getty
 2941 root      20   0  4328   40   36 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 getty
 2961 root      20   0 23384  540  156 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.88 accounts-daemon
 2965 root      20   0 29216  292   64 S   0,0  0,0   0:01.35 console-kit-dae
 3050 root      20   0 27408  320    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.48 upowerd
 3115 stenyak   20   0  6260  320   84 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.51 screen
 3119 stenyak   20   0  6260  248   40 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.61 screen
 3121 stenyak   20   0  6260  132   16 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.48 screen
 3124 stenyak   20   0  6388 1004  572 S   0,0  0,1   1:33.81 p2p.sh
 3125 stenyak   20   0 34176 5604 1764 S   0,0  0,5   1:57.10 quasselcore
 3129 stenyak   20   0 55268 2972  652 S   0,0  0,3   3:00.32 bot.py
 3280 rtkit     21   1 18980  180   64 S   0,0  0,0   0:01.23 rtkit-daemon
 3367 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kauditd
 3684 root      20   0  2940  340  112 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 udevd
 3685 root      20   0  2940  208    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 udevd
 5845 root      20   0  6444  904  592 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 cron
 5876 stenyak   20   0  1932  428  368 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 sh
 5878 stenyak   20   0  6048 1232 1080 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.00 memmon.sh
 7857 stenyak   20   0  5060  508  448 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 sleep
 9071 root      20   0  9816  860  200 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.10 sshd
 9080 stenyak   20   0 10180 1112  136 S   0,0  0,1   0:06.93 sshd
 9081 stenyak   20   0  9280 3232  148 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.62 bash
 9436 root      20   0  7396 1188  684 S   0,0  0,1   0:07.05 bitlbee
10285 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0
12728 stenyak   20   0  7960 2960  648 S   0,0  0,3  23:35.01 htop
12950 root      20   0  9832   80   76 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.08 sshd
12955 stenyak   20   0  9832    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.04 sshd
12956 stenyak   20   0  9304   36   32 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.64 bash
17939 root      20   0 23284 1080  320 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.11 gdm-simple-slav
18062 root      20   0 29808  964  364 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.38 gdm-session-wor
20066 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:09.72 kworker/0:0
28369 isabel    20   0  1932  112  108 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.03 sh
28404 isabel    20   0  3868  260   68 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.20 ssh-agent
28407 isabel    20   0  3516    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 dbus-launch
28408 isabel    20   0  3420  304  116 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.24 dbus-daemon
28416 isabel    20   0  6344  744  548 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.29 xfconfd
28422 isabel    20   0  8336  496  248 S   0,0  0,0   0:01.46 xscreensaver
28424 isabel    20   0 21932  580  340 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.17 xfce4-session
28430 isabel    20   0 24392 2032 1160 S   0,0  0,2   0:16.32 xfwm4
28432 isabel    20   0  117m 2072  908 S   0,0  0,2   0:01.26 xfce4-panel
28434 isabel    20   0 22520  256  256 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.06 Thunar
28436 isabel    20   0 21016  688  460 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.06 xfsettingsd
28437 isabel    20   0  119m 3344 1312 S   0,0  0,3   0:03.50 xfdesktop
28441 isabel    20   0 21072  272  268 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.07 kerneloops-appl
28443 isabel    20   0 29816  540  228 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.10 polkit-gnome-au
28450 isabel    20   0  263m  544  276 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.30 xfce4-volumed
28452 isabel    20   0 63936  488    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.31 tracker-store
28457 isabel    20   0 23240  768  472 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.18 xfce4-settings-
28460 isabel     9 -11 99532  500  248 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.38 pulseaudio
28470 isabel    20   0 21936  612  312 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.20 panel-6-systray
28472 isabel    20   0  339m 1348  552 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.42 xfce4-mixer-plu
28473 isabel    20   0 22028 2292 1740 S   0,0  0,2   0:59.33 xfce4-oragecloc
28514 isabel    20   0  371m  21m 2428 S   0,0  2,1   3:46.22 chromium
28517 isabel    20   0  111m 3020  288 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.58 chromium
28518 isabel    20   0  1948   64    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 chromium-sandbo
28519 isabel    20   0  120m 3324  288 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.20 chromium
28522 isabel    20   0  128m 3252  204 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.01 chromium
28558 isabel    20   0  208m  52m  476 S   0,0  5,3   1:25.92 chromium
28573 isabel    20   0  271m 103m 1244 S   0,0 10,3   3:01.64 chromium
28693 isabel    20   0  120m 3836  628 S   0,0  0,4   0:43.86 chromium
28696 isabel    20   0 83088 6412  108 S   0,0  0,6   0:16.55 GoogleTalkPlugi
28706 isabel    20   0  159m 6896  972 S   0,0  0,7   9:00.72 chromium
32332 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:06.24 kworker/1:2
32351 stenyak    9 -11 99108 1032  192 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.51 pulseaudio
32455 root      20   0  9816  108   76 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.11 sshd
32460 stenyak   20   0  9992  264  144 S   0,0  0,0   0:07.43 sshd
32462 stenyak   20   0  9300 1976  108 S   0,0  0,2   0:01.31 bash
```

Comment: Have you changed any other parameters, other than `swappiness`?

Comment: Your machine is full.  Use `top` to locate any runaway process memory wise, and restart it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no, other than uninstalling non-critical stuff (like munin, apache...) I did nothing else.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen no process is using those amounts of memory (neither VIRT, RES nor SHR), not even *close* to half a gig, so I have no idea what to kill. Again, the total used memory -/+buffers/cache is just 81megs, (and apparently only 18megs of swap are used by actual processes?).

Comment: You have a 511 MB swap partition which us fully used!  Not just 18. Trust `free`.

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea how to trace the swap usage back to a process[es] that I can kill. top doesn't say anything usefull, all the scripts at stackoverflow regarding swap usage seem to lie, and I really have no idea where the swap is being used, specially when *all* users close their X session and swap is still used :-/

Answer (score 4):

You can't swapoff because the amount of swapped memory can't be overtaken by your RAM. You are getting legitimate error message.

Small snippet.

```
if (!quiet || errno == ENOMEM)
    warn(_("%s: swapoff failed"), orig_special);

return -1;
```

In  my opinion, your workload increases your RAM demand. You are running a workload that requires more memory. Usage of the entire swap indicates that. Also, changing swappiness to 1 might not be a wise decision. Setting swappiness to 1 does not indicate that swapping will not be done. It just indicates how aggressive kernel will be in respect of swapping, it does not eliminate swapping. Swapping will happen if needs to be done.

Also, I don't know why you are trying to disable swap. Unless you have tons and tons of RAM, you should not disable swap.

Of course, you can reboot and swap usage will be zero then. And you can safely swapoff then. But, that doesn't solve the problem in long term.

Would you mind, posting the `/proc/meminfo` output.

Comment: I'm waiting for the swap to fill again (depends on computer usage, which is lower these days).
I tried to disable swap *only* in order to try/check if RAM caches would be dropped (from what I read on the net, those 904megs of cache should be discarded when more RAM is needed; and I'd need 511megs of RAM in order to disable swap).

Comment: The swap filled again yesterday. Before the user rebooted the computer, a cron-ed script managed to log some information, which I've edited into the original question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason would be for your `/tmp` to be mounted on `tmpfs`, i.e. on a file system backed by memory.

If this is the case (`df -hT /tmp`), just remove/relocate files staying there, make sure no application fills again /tmp (or any file system mounted on `tmpfs`: `df -ht tmpfs`) and this problem will be solved.

Comment: Good point. Data on `tmpfs` will typically show as _cached_.

Comment: Didn't know that! I've added `df -ht tmpfs --total` to my cron-ed debug script. Next time the problem happens, I'll post the output. One question though: should I worry about the `Used` column, or the `Size` column?

Comment: The `used` column reports the size of memory used by files. Removing these files will free memory.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is actually not bad if the system swaps out memory to the swap and uses the memory for buffers instead. This probably indicates two things:

- you do have a number of applications running (~500 MB) that are not used a lot
- you use other applications that read/write a lot of data, more than the 1 GB of RAM that you have. The system tries to improve performance for these applications by buffering hard disk data in memory for faster access

Yes, it may appear that you only have ~600 MB memory in use. What is causing the system to swap is probably not an overly memory exhaustive application, but a very I/O heavy workload hitting the buffers. Can you identify which process is doing all the I/O? What are you using the server for?

Comment: At the time of low memory usage, the *only* graphical application running is gdm3. Previously (before the user logged out), an xfce desktop was running, with barely any widgets, and only chromium-browser showing on its task manager.

When it happens again, I'll use iotop to look for I/O intensive processes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I/O heaviness should not by itself result in swapping. You use a stock kernel?  If yes, it must be a user program with a memory leak.

Comment: I found Chrome pretty much unusable with just 1 GB of RAM. Sure it is fast and has sandboxing, put you pay for that with memory intensiveness. But that wouldn't explain why your system uses 900 MB for caching.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the kernel is the stock one: `3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.32-1 i686 GNU/Linux`
Any idea how to track a possible memory leak to the originator process when top does not show anything unusual?

Answer (score 1):

<s>I do not know of a tool that gives you the swap size on a per process basis, but it would be easy enough to write one... (see shell script example further down)</s>

Linux comes with a tool named `smem`. To install under Debian/Ubuntu you should be able to use (it will install many python packages in the process):

```
apt-get install smem
```

Then to use it, just type `smem` on your command line.

---

The other solution to find out how much a process current swap usage is, you want to check out the **VmSwap** parameter in the process `status` file.

Using `top` or `htop` or `ps` or `pgrep` or `pidof`... determine the process identifier (`PID`) and then look at the status file:

```
$ pidof myprocess
123
$ cat /proc/123/status
```

This includes information about the memory currently used by the process. There is an example:

```
Name:   snapinit
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   2769
Ngid:   0
Pid:    2769
PPid:   1
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    0   0   0   0
Gid:    0   0   0   0
FDSize: 64
Groups: 
NStgid: 2769
NSpid:  2769
NSpgid: 2765
NSsid:  2765
VmPeak:   141952 kB
VmSize:   141952 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     11552 kB
VmRSS:      3444 kB
VmData:      772 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:       244 kB
VmLib:     62356 kB
VmPTE:       208 kB
VmPMD:        12 kB
VmSwap:     1968 kB
HugetlbPages:          0 kB
Threads:    1
SigQ:   0/3912
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000014006
SigIgn: 0000000000001000
SigCgt: 00000001800004c8
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000003fffffffff
CapEff: 0000003fffffffff
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
Seccomp:    0
Cpus_allowed:   1
Cpus_allowed_list:  0
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    36
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 23
```

The section of interest is the one showing `Vm<name>` parameters (i.e. virtual memory which is the only kind of memory available to a process, only the kernel deals with real physical memory; the VM is created by your [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)):

```
VmPeak:   141952 kB
VmSize:   141952 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     11552 kB
VmRSS:      3444 kB
VmData:      772 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:       244 kB
VmLib:     62356 kB
VmPTE:       208 kB
VmPMD:        12 kB
VmSwap:     1968 kB
```

In my case, I see that the swap memory (VmSwap) used by this process alone is 1968Kb, nearly 2Mb.

The VmLib parameter shows the amount of memory used for shared libraries (.so files). Although this look huge, remember that the memory used by shared libraries is... shared between all processes.

In a shell, you may retrieve the parameters with a command line like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "  NAME                        PID        SWAP"
for PID in /proc/[0-9]*
do
  if stat $PID/status >/dev/null
  then
    # get name of process
    procname=`grep 'Name:' $PID/status | awk -e '{ print $2 };'`
    # get amount of swap in use by that process
    procswap=`grep 'VmSwap:' $PID/status | awk -e '{ print $2 };'`

    printf "%-21s %11d %11d\n" $procname `basename $PID` $procswap
  fi
done
```

Note that the $PID/status file will disappear when a process dies and this for loop does not check that properly. Also some files cannot be read by a normal user (i.e. if you are root, you'll see a result for each process, otherwise some processes just return an error or 0Kb.)

There is a sample output. The SWAP data is in *Kilo Bytes*.

```
  NAME                        PID        SWAP
systemd                         1         348
watchdog/0                     10           0
ipv6_addrconf                 106           0
ureadahead                  13234          28
gnome-calculato             13997           0
apache2                     14175        7240
freshclam                    1447        3072
systemd-logind               1449         244
```

Answer (score -1):

swap is full so that's why you have to stop some process, for **killing** **process use** `kill -9 PID` 
**And then use** 
`sudo swapoff  -a`

In my condition i stop my sidekiq worker and then reallocated the swap memory.

[digitalocean server swap memory](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04)